# Mysql Query on Group by issues Please help me..?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

My tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `maf_game` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `maf_game` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Finders Keepers'),
(2, 'My american farm');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `maf_game_stats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sessionid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `gid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `result` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `accesstime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


INSERT INTO `maf_game_stats` (`id`, `userid`, `sessionid`, `gid`, `qid`, `result`, `accesstime`) VALUES
(1, '514c550391709', 'dicuu6e5bhv9j8com9fq38ipe2', 1, 1, '1', '2013-03-22 18:26:41'),
(2, '514c550391709', 'dicuu6e5bhv9j8com9fq38ipe2', 1, 2, '1', '2013-03-22 18:26:43'),
(3, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 1, 1, '1', '2013-03-22 18:27:15'),
(4, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 1, 2, '1', '2013-03-22 18:27:17'),
(5, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 1, 3, '0', '2013-03-22 18:27:21'),
(6, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 1, 4, '1', '2013-03-22 18:27:23'),
(7, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 1, 5, '1', '2013-03-22 18:28:28'),
(8, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 2, 1, '1', '2013-03-22 18:29:01'),
(9, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 2, 2, '1', '2013-03-22 18:29:02'),
(10, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 2, 3, '1', '2013-03-22 18:29:07'),
(11, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 2, 4, '0', '2013-03-22 18:29:09'),
(12, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 2, 5, '1', '2013-03-22 18:29:10'),
(13, '514c58b1372e7', 'e70qhplor1v1ht2o3f17e2l3j3', 2, 1, '0', '2013-03-22 18:42:22'),
(14, '514c58b1372e7', 'e70qhplor1v1ht2o3f17e2l3j3', 2, 2, '0', '2013-03-22 18:42:24'),
(15, '514c58b1372e7', 'e70qhplor1v1ht2o3f17e2l3j3', 2, 3, '0', '2013-03-22 18:42:26'),
(16, '514c58b1372e7', 'e70qhplor1v1ht2o3f17e2l3j3', 2, 4, '0', '2013-03-22 18:42:27'),
(17, '514c58b1372e7', 'e70qhplor1v1ht2o3f17e2l3j3', 2, 5, '0', '2013-03-22 18:42:29'),
(18, '514c5baf5ef35', 'hn7q2cd4575864pm6etkmkdfh2', 2, 1, '1', '2013-03-22 18:55:07'),
(19, '514c5baf5ef35', 'hn7q2cd4575864pm6etkmkdfh2', 2, 2, '1', '2013-03-22 18:55:08'),
(20, '514c5baf5ef35', 'hn7q2cd4575864pm6etkmkdfh2', 2, 3, '1', '2013-03-22 18:55:14'),
(21, '514c5baf5ef35', 'hn7q2cd4575864pm6etkmkdfh2', 2, 4, '1', '2013-03-22 18:55:15'),
(22, '514c5c8f5b55e', 'a36enh6d78dm8cao4a3ibqj4s0', 1, 1, '1', '2013-03-22 18:58:50'),
(23, '514c5c8f5b55e', 'a36enh6d78dm8cao4a3ibqj4s0', 1, 2, '1', '2013-03-22 18:58:52');
```

My Written Query is :

```
SELECT D.gid, D.qid, D.result, COUNT(D.id) AS staus FROM 
(SELECT MIN(id) AS id, userid, gid, qid, result, accesstime FROM maf_game_stats WHERE gid=2 GROUP BY userid, qid) AS D 
GROUP BY D.qid, D.result
```

Above Query result:

```
gid qid result  staus
2   1   0       1
2   1   1       2
2   2   0       1
2   2   1       2
2   3   0       1
2   3   1       2
2   4   0       2
2   4   1       1
2   5   0       1
2   5   1       1
```

its working fine but I Want result is like Ex:

1. How many students got each question Correct / Incorrect on their first attempt?

result

```
--------------------------------------------
gid qid Correct Incorrect
-------------------------------------------
1   1   3      10       
1   2   8      1        
1   3   2      5
1   4   1      7    
1   5   4      3
```

Please any suggestions....?

Thanks!
Vasanth


22MR2013

Sorry i Forgot..... who took first attempt

1. How many students got each question Correct / Incorrect on their first attempt?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `maf_game` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;


INSERT INTO `maf_game` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Finders Keepers'),
(2, 'My american farm'),
(3, 'Stewardship'),
(4, 'Harvet This');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `maf_game_stats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sessionid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `gid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `result` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `accesstime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)  ;



INSERT INTO `maf_game_stats` (`id`, `userid`, `sessionid`, `gid`, `qid`, `result`, `accesstime`) VALUES
(1, '514c550391709', 'dicuu6e5bhv9j8com9fq38ipe2', 1, 1, '1', '2013-03-22 18:26:41'),
(2, '514c550391709', 'dicuu6e5bhv9j8com9fq38ipe2', 1, 2, '1', '2013-03-22 18:26:43'),
(3, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 1, 1, '1', '2013-03-22 18:27:15'),
(4, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 1, 2, '1', '2013-03-22 18:27:17'),
(5, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 1, 3, '0', '2013-03-22 18:27:21'),
(6, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 1, 4, '1', '2013-03-22 18:27:23'),
(7, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 1, 5, '1', '2013-03-22 18:28:28'),
(8, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 2, 1, '1', '2013-03-22 18:29:01'),
(9, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 2, 2, '1', '2013-03-22 18:29:02'),
(10, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 2, 3, '1', '2013-03-22 18:29:07'),
(11, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 2, 4, '0', '2013-03-22 18:29:09'),
(12, '514c5521c63e1', 'f3ffkgsdejo9luulgfn2i5lv60', 2, 5, '1', '2013-03-22 18:29:10'),
(13, '514c58b1372e7', 'e70qhplor1v1ht2o3f17e2l3j3', 2, 1, '0', '2013-03-22 18:42:22'),
(14, '514c58b1372e7', 'e70qhplor1v1ht2o3f17e2l3j3', 2, 2, '0', '2013-03-22 18:42:24'),
(15, '514c58b1372e7', 'e70qhplor1v1ht2o3f17e2l3j3', 2, 3, '0', '2013-03-22 18:42:26'),
(16, '514c58b1372e7', 'e70qhplor1v1ht2o3f17e2l3j3', 2, 4, '0', '2013-03-22 18:42:27'),
(17, '514c58b1372e7', 'e70qhplor1v1ht2o3f17e2l3j3', 2, 5, '0', '2013-03-22 18:42:29'),
(18, '514c5baf5ef35', 'hn7q2cd4575864pm6etkmkdfh2', 2, 1, '1', '2013-03-22 18:55:07'),
(19, '514c5baf5ef35', 'hn7q2cd4575864pm6etkmkdfh2', 2, 2, '1', '2013-03-22 18:55:08'),
(20, '514c5baf5ef35', 'hn7q2cd4575864pm6etkmkdfh2', 2, 3, '1', '2013-03-22 18:55:14'),
(21, '514c5baf5ef35', 'hn7q2cd4575864pm6etkmkdfh2', 2, 4, '1', '2013-03-22 18:55:15'),
(22, '514c5c8f5b55e', 'a36enh6d78dm8cao4a3ibqj4s0', 1, 1, '1', '2013-03-22 18:58:50'),
(23, '514c5c8f5b55e', 'a36enh6d78dm8cao4a3ibqj4s0', 1, 2, '1', '2013-03-22 18:58:52'),
(24, '514c5c968de28', '5nfatkpl301k9povksp8seteu3', 3, 1, '1', '2013-03-22 20:06:29'),
(25, '514c5c968de28', '5nfatkpl301k9povksp8seteu3', 3, 2, '1', '2013-03-22 20:06:31'),
(26, '514c5c968de28', '5nfatkpl301k9povksp8seteu3', 3, 3, '1', '2013-03-22 20:06:34'),
(27, '514c6c75405dc', 'jhpoub8ueva48ja5glvt9rhsl6', 3, 1, '1', '2013-03-22 20:06:41'),
(28, '514c6c75405dc', 'jhpoub8ueva48ja5glvt9rhsl6', 3, 2, '1', '2013-03-22 20:06:43'),
(29, '514c6c75405dc', 'jhpoub8ueva48ja5glvt9rhsl6', 3, 3, '1', '2013-03-22 20:06:45'),
(30, '514c6c75405dc', 'jhpoub8ueva48ja5glvt9rhsl6', 3, 4, '1', '2013-03-22 20:06:47'),
(31, '514c6c75405dc', 'jhpoub8ueva48ja5glvt9rhsl6', 3, 5, '1', '2013-03-22 20:06:49'),
(32, '514c6c8351cf3', 'rfa7agnrt63m2rk58legl7fr95', 3, 1, '0', '2013-03-22 20:06:55'),
(33, '514c6c8351cf3', 'rfa7agnrt63m2rk58legl7fr95', 3, 2, '1', '2013-03-22 20:06:56'),
(34, '514c6c8351cf3', 'rfa7agnrt63m2rk58legl7fr95', 3, 3, '0', '2013-03-22 20:06:58'),
(35, '514c6c8351cf3', 'rfa7agnrt63m2rk58legl7fr95', 3, 4, '0', '2013-03-22 20:06:59'),
(36, '514c6c8351cf3', 'rfa7agnrt63m2rk58legl7fr95', 3, 5, '1', '2013-03-22 20:07:00'),
(37, '514d3307066c4', 'kdmcg2lc3a0c1ts82860lt8fg1', 2, 1, '0', '2013-03-23 10:26:56'),
(38, '514d3307066c4', 'kdmcg2lc3a0c1ts82860lt8fg1', 2, 2, '1', '2013-03-23 10:26:58'),
(39, '514d3307066c4', 'kdmcg2lc3a0c1ts82860lt8fg1', 2, 3, '0', '2013-03-23 10:26:59'),
(40, '514d3307066c4', 'kdmcg2lc3a0c1ts82860lt8fg1', 2, 4, '0', '2013-03-23 10:27:00'),
(41, '514d3307066c4', 'kdmcg2lc3a0c1ts82860lt8fg1', 2, 5, '1', '2013-03-23 10:27:01'),
(42, '514d3307066c4', 'kdmcg2lc3a0c1ts82860lt8fg1', 1, 1, '1', '2013-03-23 10:27:04'),
(43, '514d3307066c4', 'kdmcg2lc3a0c1ts82860lt8fg1', 1, 2, '1', '2013-03-23 10:27:06'),
(44, '514d3307066c4', 'kdmcg2lc3a0c1ts82860lt8fg1', 1, 3, '1', '2013-03-23 10:27:09'),
(45, '514d3307066c4', 'kdmcg2lc3a0c1ts82860lt8fg1', 1, 4, '1', '2013-03-23 10:27:10'),
(46, '514d3307066c4', 'kdmcg2lc3a0c1ts82860lt8fg1', 1, 5, '1', '2013-03-23 10:27:11'),
(47, '514d3307066c4', 'kdmcg2lc3a0c1ts82860lt8fg1', 4, 1, '1', '2013-03-23 10:27:14'),
(48, '514d3307066c4', 'kdmcg2lc3a0c1ts82860lt8fg1', 4, 2, '1', '2013-03-23 10:27:15'),
(49, '514d3307066c4', 'kdmcg2lc3a0c1ts82860lt8fg1', 4, 3, '1', '2013-03-23 10:27:18'),
(50, '514d3307066c4', 'kdmcg2lc3a0c1ts82860lt8fg1', 4, 4, '1', '2013-03-23 10:27:19'),
(51, '514d3307066c4', 'kdmcg2lc3a0c1ts82860lt8fg1', 4, 5, '1', '2013-03-23 10:27:20'),
(52, '514d363fd70d1', 'h82qih1hb3spv0fk4k1h3cdg10', 2, 1, '1', '2013-03-23 10:27:40'),
(53, '514d363fd70d1', 'h82qih1hb3spv0fk4k1h3cdg10', 2, 2, '1', '2013-03-23 10:27:41'),
(54, '514d363fd70d1', 'h82qih1hb3spv0fk4k1h3cdg10', 2, 3, '1', '2013-03-23 10:27:43'),
(55, '514d363fd70d1', 'h82qih1hb3spv0fk4k1h3cdg10', 2, 4, '1', '2013-03-23 10:27:44'),
(56, '514d363fd70d1', 'h82qih1hb3spv0fk4k1h3cdg10', 2, 5, '1', '2013-03-23 10:27:45'),
(57, '514d363fd70d1', 'h82qih1hb3spv0fk4k1h3cdg10', 1, 1, '1', '2013-03-23 11:04:50'),
(58, '514d363fd70d1', 'h82qih1hb3spv0fk4k1h3cdg10', 1, 2, '1', '2013-03-23 11:05:04'),
(59, '514d363fd70d1', 'h82qih1hb3spv0fk4k1h3cdg10', 1, 3, '1', '2013-03-23 11:05:06'),
(60, '514d363fd70d1', 'h82qih1hb3spv0fk4k1h3cdg10', 1, 4, '0', '2013-03-23 11:05:06'),
(61, '514d363fd70d1', 'h82qih1hb3spv0fk4k1h3cdg10', 1, 5, '0', '2013-03-23 11:05:07'),
(62, '514d363fd70d1', 'h82qih1hb3spv0fk4k1h3cdg10', 1, 1, '0', '2013-03-23 11:05:11'),
(63, '514d363fd70d1', 'h82qih1hb3spv0fk4k1h3cdg10', 1, 2, '1', '2013-03-23 11:05:12'),
(64, '514d363fd70d1', 'h82qih1hb3spv0fk4k1h3cdg10', 1, 3, '1', '2013-03-23 11:05:15'),
(65, '514d363fd70d1', 'h82qih1hb3spv0fk4k1h3cdg10', 1, 4, '1', '2013-03-23 11:05:19'),
(66, '514d363fd70d1', 'h82qih1hb3spv0fk4k1h3cdg10', 1, 5, '1', '2013-03-23 11:05:20');
```

Comment: how about this? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49401e/5

Comment: on the record above, what userid, who took the questiion twice? I can't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  GID, QID, 
        SUM(Result = 1) Correct,
        SUM(Result = 0) Incorrect
FROM    maf_game_stats
GROUP   BY GID, QID
```

Comment: Hi Sir, the given query Work for me thanks lot...:) you saved me..:)

Comment: (on the record above, what userid, who took the questiion twice?)Sorry I have updates the db please refer the above sir.

Comment: @vasanthnaidu from the records given on your update, can you tell what will be the exact result? `:)`

Comment: what do you mean by first attemp? because i can see any multiple records of the same `userid, dig, qid`.

Comment: How many students got each question Correct / Incorrect on their first attempt?

Comment: yesterday given query correct but i need their first attemps for gid 1,qid 1, 2, 3, ....5 or 10. but qid no repeat and correct/ incorrect

Comment: sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74718b/4 from this we are getting result multiple attempts ex: user 57 - 66 '514d363fd70d1' attempt gid=1 qid 2 times but i need only first attempts only

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74718b/8  Please see result correct but i need your yesterday given query format